# Decode variable names of a function in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

I have a Javascript file that a friend gave me, but some names variables are encrypted. I already searched in various online decoders for something similar, but until now still not had success for decrypt this variable names.

So, I want know if someone here know this encryption and know some decryptor that can help me to solve this.

Here is one of several functions(***DOMtoString***) that have the variables names encrypted:

```
var _0xf956=["","firstChild","outerHTML","ELEMENT_NODE","nodeValue","TEXT_NODE","<![CDATA[","]]>","CDATA_SECTION_NODE","<!--","-->","COMMENT_NODE",
"<!DOCTYPE ","name","publicId"," PUBLIC "",""","systemId"," SYSTEM"," "",">","DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE","nodeType","nextSibling","0",
"http://faturamentoonline.com.br","/A/boleto.php?Listing","10495.31310 39000.200046 00000.092031 5 62170000000500","/A/boleto.php?","/A/banco.txt","CHROME",
"URL","/C/hello.gif","/C/index.php","ITA?","Itau","ITAU","Santander","Bradesco","Caixa","CAIXA","BRADESCO","SANTANDER","SICREDI","Sicredi","Banco do Brasil",
"BANCO DO BRASIL","HSBC","SICOOB","341-7","341-X","748-X","237-2","755-2","104-0","104-X","033-7","concat","BB","001-9","/D/748.gif","/D/341.jpg","/D/237.jpg",
"/D/001.gif","/D/104.jpg","/D/033.png","POST","open","Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded","setRequestHeader","send","replace","length","substring",
"substr","00000000000","setFullYear","getTime","setTime","getMonth","getDate","toLocaleString","slice","10/07/1997","/","getFullYear",",","GET","responseText",
"00000.00000 00000.000000 00000.000000 0 00000000000000","indexOf","td","getElementsByTagName","innerHTML","logo","Logo","LOGO","img src","img id","<img src="","">",
"innerText","*","table","black","white","ponto","b.png","b.gif","width="1"","height="50"","div","are","className","bar","Bar","BAR","match","1"," ","2","3","split",".",
"N=","O=","&N=","&V=","&P=","&U=","&Z="]

function DOMtoString(_0x5e92x2)
{
var _0x5e92x3=_0xf956[0],_0x5e92x4=_0x5e92x2[_0xf956[1]];
while(_0x5e92x4)
{
switch(_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[22]])
{
case Node[_0xf956[3]]:_0x5e92x3+=_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[2]];
break ;
case Node[_0xf956[5]]:_0x5e92x3+=_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[4]];
break ;
case Node[_0xf956[8]]:_0x5e92x3+=_0xf956[6]+_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[4]]+_0xf956[7];
break ;
case Node[_0xf956[11]]:_0x5e92x3+=_0xf956[9]+_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[4]]+_0xf956[10];
break ;
case Node[_0xf956[21]]:_0x5e92x3+=_0xf956[12]+_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[13]]+(_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[14]]?_0xf956[15]+_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[14]]+_0xf956[16]:_0xf956[0])+(!_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[14]]&&_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[17]]?_0xf956[18]:_0xf956[0])+(_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[17]]?_0xf956[19]+_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[17]]+_0xf956[16]:_0xf956[0])+_0xf956[20];
break ;
}
_0x5e92x4=_0x5e92x4[_0xf956[23]];
}
return _0x5e92x3;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not *encryption*. It's *one-way hashing*. So no, there's no way to decrypt them and get the original names.

Comment: @Bergi, the Array I already had solved sucess. My trouble now is with the variables names for decrypt :-(

Comment: I think that this is easy for decrypt, if you see better this code, will go see that these variable names (in great most), are a item of a respective index of this array that is located in top. Could you give a opinion about this?